# Uploading of Infected Files/Videos should not be allowed.Even if allowed file/video types (.mp4) are being uploaded

Tags: c#

I am working for a website where user can only upload .mp4 videos.The Uploading of Infected Files/Videos should not be allowed.It should fail even if allowed file/video types (.mp4) are being uploaded.
Can anyone help me out in this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and only one I can think of) solution would involve a file content check and a conditional deletion ( and maybe a notification to the uploader) *immediately after* the upload.